# How can i push array in matrix vertically?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, matrix

```
const axaliGamoshveba = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < gamoshvebisMult.length; i++) {
    axaliGamoshveba[0].push(gamoshvebisMult[i].Soflis);
    axaliGamoshveba[1].push(gamoshvebisMult[i].Samto);
    axaliGamoshveba[2].push(gamoshvebisMult[i].Damamushavebeli);
    axaliGamoshveba[3].push(gamoshvebisMult[i].Eleqtroenergiis);
    axaliGamoshveba[4].push(gamoshvebisMult[i].Wyalbobarageba);
    axaliGamoshveba[5].push(gamoshvebisMult[i].Mshenebloba);
    axaliGamoshveba[6].push(gamoshvebisMult[i].Sabitumo);
    axaliGamoshveba[7].push(gamoshvebisMult[i].Transporti);
    axaliGamoshveba[8].push(gamoshvebisMult[i].Gantavsebis);
    axaliGamoshveba[9].push(gamoshvebisMult[i].Informacia);
    axaliGamoshveba[10].push(gamoshvebisMult[i].Safinanso);
    axaliGamoshveba[11].push(gamoshvebisMult[i].UdzraviQoneba);
    axaliGamoshveba[12].push(gamoshvebisMult[i].Profesiuli);
    axaliGamoshveba[13].push(gamoshvebisMult[i].Administraciuli);
    axaliGamoshveba[14].push(gamoshvebisMult[i].Saxelmwifo);
    axaliGamoshveba[15].push(gamoshvebisMult[i].Ganatleba);
    axaliGamoshveba[16].push(gamoshvebisMult[i].Jandacva);
    axaliGamoshveba[17].push(gamoshvebisMult[i].Xelovneba);
    axaliGamoshveba[18].push(gamoshvebisMult[i].Sxva);
    axaliGamoshveba[19].push(gamoshvebisMult[i].Shinameurneoba);
  }
```

I have my array from MySQL server and want to create matrix, but when I push my arrays like that, it adds horizontally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const axaliGamoshveba = [
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
  ];

  for (let i = 0; i < gamoshvebisMult.length; i++) {
    axaliGamoshveba[i].push(
      gamoshvebisMult[i].Soflis,
      gamoshvebisMult[i].Samto,
      gamoshvebisMult[i].Damamushavebeli,
      gamoshvebisMult[i].Eleqtroenergiis,
      gamoshvebisMult[i].Wyalbobarageba,
      gamoshvebisMult[i].Mshenebloba,
      gamoshvebisMult[i].Sabitumo,
      gamoshvebisMult[i].Transporti,
      gamoshvebisMult[i].Gantavsebis,
      gamoshvebisMult[i].Informacia,
      gamoshvebisMult[i].Safinanso,
      gamoshvebisMult[i].UdzraviQoneba,
      gamoshvebisMult[i].Profesiuli,
      gamoshvebisMult[i].Administraciuli,
      gamoshvebisMult[i].Saxelmwifo,
      gamoshvebisMult[i].Ganatleba,
      gamoshvebisMult[i].Jandacva,
      gamoshvebisMult[i].Xelovneba,
      gamoshvebisMult[i].Sxva,
      gamoshvebisMult[i].Shinameurneoba
    );
  }
```

I fixed it by adding my data differently

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

join the items with newlines:

```
var axaliGamoshveba = ['one', 'two', 'three']
element.textContent = array.join('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by - *How can I push array in matrix vertically ?*

If you want to print the array items vertically, then you can print each element vertically by using [Array.join(`<br>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Demo **:**

```js
const axaliGamoshveba = [["Alpha"], ["Beta"], ["Gama"], ["Omega"]];

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = axaliGamoshveba.join('<br>');
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```